# Colouring substrings

Tags: bash

I would like to take a string and colour the parts passed by arguments to the function.

Consider a string

```
str="[Title] Some Description"
```

Then calling

```
glow "[" "]" "$str"
```

would colour the square brackets blue whilst keeping the
rest at the default terminal colour.  Meaning that `Title` and `Some Description` would use the default terminal colour.

Here in another example that would colour the word `random` blue,

```
str="This is some random sentence."
glow "random" "$str"
```

Comment: It is unclear whether you want the characters `[` and `]` coloured blue regardless of where in `$str` they occur or whether you want to colour any string delimited by `[` at the start and `]` at the end in blue (and how nested such strings should be handled). I also wonder why you would want to do this in `bash` rather than employ some already existing syntax highlighting solution.  Since you have had answers to this in other forums, it may benefit you to use these as examples of how you don't want to do it, and at the same time explain why.

Comment: Only the characters or strings passed to the function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: At any rate, could you also explain what existing syntax highlighting solutions you are referring to ? I would check them out.

Comment: I can't as there is no mentioning of what the input may possibly look like, whether it is a known format or whether it is just random text. It is also not possible to suggest a wide arrange of other solutions because all we know is that you use `bash`.  For all that we know, this could be on Windows, Plan 9, OpenBSD or any other system that is able to run `bash`.

Comment: It is for random text and have included an example string.  I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent-enough Bash (ones supporting `patsub_replacement`, which might mean 5.2), something like this might work:

```
color_me_blue() {
    blue=$'\e[1;34m'
    normal=$'\e[0m'
    pattern="$1"
    string="$2"
    string=${string//$pattern/$blue&$normal}
    echo "$string"
}

color_me_blue '[][]' '[hello] there'
str="This is some random sentence."
color_me_blue 'random' "$str"
```

That first parameter is taken as a shell pattern, and `[][]` is one that matches `[` or `]` (same as `[abc]` matches any of the three letters).

Without support for putting the substituted string back, it's harder, so for older Bashes I think one would have to fork out a `sed`:

```
sed_me_blue() {
    blue=$'\e[1;34m'
    normal=$'\e[0m'
    regex="$1"
    string="$2"
    string="$(sed -e "s/$regex/$blue&$normal/" <<< "$string")"
    echo "$string"
}
```

This is way more fragile, what with having to embed the pattern into the sed code. At least any unquoted slashes would cause issues there, and there are likely injection vulnerabilities there, also.
Also here, the pattern is a regex and not a shell pattern, not that it makes a difference for `[][]`.

Comment: Good.  But the pattern is being replaced by the character `&`.

Comment: @Randy, yes, that's the thing about needing a recent-enough Bash... The sed-style thing of dropping the matched string in place of the `&` in the replacement string is a new feature. In the older versions, the `&` is just a regular character.

Comment: Have installed `bash-5.2` and got a good result.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#!/bin/bash

glow() {
    l=$1
    r=$2
    str=$3

    glow_on='\E[37;46;1m'
    glow_off='\E[0m'

    strl=${str/$l/$glow_on$l}
    strlr=${strl/$r/$r$glow_off}

    echo -e "$strlr"
}       

glow "[" "]" "[Title] Some Description"
```